# Tumblr photosets, image on image

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I'm working on a tumblr theme for a magazine I am working on, but I'm stuck with the photosets blocks.

I'd like to have two image layered with a hover function to make the first one disappear when you put your mouse.

I think my css is quite good for that but the problem is that for photosets tumblr create an external page with its own css and I don't know how to modify it. I just can get opacity effect using iframe.photoset but it's not enough to modify the place of my image.

This is the css I apply to the photoset:

```
.photoset {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}


.photoset_row {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
}

    .photoset_row:first-child {
        display: block;
    }

.photoset:hover .photoset_row {
    display: block;
}

.html_photoset:hover .photoset_row:fisrt-child {
    display: none;
}
```

I was thinking to use maybe JS like that (test with a shake effect) but I'm not a web designer and that look too hard for me.

```
{block:Photoset}
<div class="photoset">
    <div class="shakeImage" onMouseover="init(this);rattleimage()"  onClick="top.focus()"/>
{Photoset-500}
</div>
```

So if you have an idea for this problem that would be really great!

Comment: Try spelling `fisrt-child` the right way and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Doesn't work neither. This is the link of the page, the first post with two image is the test. http://cent-dix-sept.tumblr.com/